# ¿Problema para actualizar registro con combobox?

Tags: php, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy actualizando una columna de la BD mediante un `<select> option` pero al ejecutar el codigo no actualiza la columna. Estoy utilizando MySQL.

Prueba1.php

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="Prueba2.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="servicio_No" value="<?php echo                $servicio_No ?>" />

            <input type="text" name="servicio_No" value="" placeholder="Ingrese el numero del servicio">

            <label>Situacion: </label>
            <select name="situacion" id="situacion">
                <option value="Finalizado">Finalizado</option>
                <option value="Fallido">Fallido</option>
                <option value="Cancelado">Cancelado</option>
                <option value="Programado">Programado</option>
                <option value="Realizando">Realizando</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update" placeholder="">
       </form>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Prueba2.php

```
<?php
    $conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin123", "database");

    $servicio_No = $_POST["servicio_No"];
    $situacion = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['situacion']);

    $update_query = "UPDATE servicio SET servicio_No = '". $_POST['servicio_No'] ."' WHERE situacion = '". $_POST['situacion']."')" ;

    mysqli_query($conexion, $update_query); 

    mysqli_close($conexion);;
?>
```

Comment: Cristian continuando la pregunta de ayer por si no lo has resuelto, el campo servicio_No es autoincrement y este tipo de campo ha de ser único y generalemte consecutivo para mantener la integridad de los datos, por lo que si haces un update y es un número ya utilizado no se ejecutará, y si hay más de una tupla susceptible de actualizarse (con igual situación), tampoco va a funcionar bien. Quizás deberías cambiar el diseño de la tabla.

Answer (score 2):

Te falta ejecutar la query y te falta una comilla en la query

```
 $conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin123", "database");

$servicio_No = $_POST["servicio_No"];
$situacion = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['situacion']);

$update_query = "UPDATE servicio SET servicio_No = '". $_POST['servicio_No'] ."' WHERE situacion = '". $_POST['situacion']."'" ;

mysqli_query($conexion, $update_query); /* Esto es lo que falta*/

mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: el resultado  es igual no cambia

Comment: ¿De que tipo son los campos?

Comment: situacion en varchar y el numero del servicio int

Comment: Tiene pinta de que no mapea registros. Habria que ver la BBDD

Comment: como te la muestro?

Comment: Pon el script de creación en la pregunta.

Comment: puse una imagen

Comment: Pon el script mejor, en la imagen no viene toda la información.

Answer (score 1):

JDev ya te dió la respuesta pero si sigue sin funcionar, hay que hacer varias validaciones, mira

```
<?php
$conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin123", "database");

//Validar si la conexión es correcta
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo 'Falló la conexión a la base de datos';
}

else{
  //Validar si los parámetros enviados son correctos
  if( empty( $_POST["servicio_No"] ) || empty( $_POST['situacion'] ) ){
        echo 'Los parámetros están vacíos';
  }

  else{
      //Limpiar las variables
      $servicio = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST["servicio_No"]);
      $situacion = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['situacion']);
      $query = "UPDATE servicio SET servicio_No = ". $servicio ." WHERE situacion = '". $situacion ."'";
      mysqli_query( $conexion, $query );
      //Validar que se haya hecho el UPDATE
      if( mysqli_affected_rows($conexion) <= 0){
        echo 'No fue posible crear la consulta, verifica: <br>' . $query;
      }

      else{
        echo 'Actualización exitosa';
      }
  }
}

mysqli_close($conexion);


?>
```

Comment: voy a jecutar estas validaciones ya te dio el resultado

Comment: este fue el resultado : No fue posible crear la consulta, verifica:

Comment: Entonces hay un problema de sintaxis en la consulta, agarra la consulta y metela directo en tu manejador de base de datos.

Comment: con variable incluida?

Answer (score 0):

Problema de comillas,

```
$update_query = "UPDATE servicio SET servicio_No = '". $_POST['servicio_No'] ."' WHERE situacion = '". $_POST['situacion']."' " ;
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78796/discussion-on-answer-by-carmen-problema-para-actualizar-registro-con-combobox).

Comment: Recordad ir borrando comentarios obsoletos para no tener tantos mensajes en la publicacion y asi tenerla más ordenada. Un saludo